# Find the distribution of X/(X + Y).

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let X and Y be independent random variables each having a geometric distribution.

Find the distribution of $\frac{X}{(X + Y)}$. [Define $\frac{X}{(X + Y)}$ to be zero if
$X + Y= 0$]

I have an idea of how to do it but not if it is correct

Let Z=$\frac{X}{(X + Y)}$

so $f(z)$= $0$ if $ x=0$, $1$ if $ x>0$ and $Y=0$

but I don't know what happens when $ X>0$ and $Y>0$

help  :(

Comment: This is problem 4.16b in Statistical Inference 2nd edition by Casella and Berger.  Just got through it myself. I got the same approach as the given answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides $0$, the possible values of $X/(X+Y)$ are rational numbers $a/b$ for integers $b \ge a \ge 1$.  Note that the same rational $a/b$ can come from $(ka)/(kb)$ for any positive integer $k$, i.e.
$$\mathbb P\left(\frac{X}{X+Y} = \frac{a}{b}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb P(X=ka, Y=k(b-a))$$