# Find the distribution of $Z = X/(X + Y )$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables with the same geometric distribution $\left(P(X=x|p)=p(1-p)^{x-1}\right)$.

Find the distribution of $Z = X/(X + Y )$, where we define $Z = 0$  if  $X + Y = 0$.

Hello, I need help with this question I start by letting x/(x+y)=r/s where r and s are positive integers and s>r but I don't know where to go from here. can someone help me?

Comment: Since there are multiple definitions of the geometric distribution, you need to specify which one you are using.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3676989/321264

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $a/a+b$ is in lowest terms, $a<b$.  Then $X/(X+Y)=a/(a+b)$ if there is some integer $k$ such that $X=ka$ and $Y=kb$.  So

$$P\left(X/(X+Y)=a/(a+b)\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P(X=ka)P(Y=kb)\\=\sum_k p^2(1-p)^{k(a+b)-2} \\= \frac{p^2(1-p)^{a+b-2}}{1-(1-p)^{a+b}}.$$

This interestingly enough doesn't depend on $a$, only on $a+b$.